# Change menu item format when selected

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the color of a selected li item by class by cobbling together different parts of examples and obviously missing something.

If it isn't clear I'm a noob to css and jquery.

Thanks for looking.

html

```
<div class="menuwrapper">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
/* Define the body style */
 body {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:12px;
}
/* Remove the margin, padding, and list style of UL and LI components */
 .menuwrapper ul, .menuwrapper ul li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
/* Apply background color and border bottom white and width to 150px */
 .menuwrapper ul li {
    background-color:#7f95db;
    border-bottom:solid 1px white;
    width:150px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
/*Apply the background hover color when user hover the mouse over of the li component */
 .menuwrapper ul li:hover {
    background-color:#6679e9;
    position:relative;
}
/* Apply the link style */
 .menuwrapper ul li a {
    padding:5px 15px;
    color:#ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
/* Apply the background select color when the li component is selected */
 .menuselected li {
    background-color:#6679e9;
    border-bottom:solid 1px white;
    width:190px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

jscript

```
    var main = function () {
    $(".menuwrapper ul li").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('menuselected'); /*this applies class but does not change style of li element */
        //$(this).css("background-color","#ffaa99"); //this works when uncommented
    })
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

link to code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Teeroy71/vrx6bqa4/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the css definition. You are adding the class to the `li` element so the css definition `.menuselected li` is wrong because it looks for a `li` child which is inside a `.menuselected` element.

Also you have a problem with [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), the rule `.menuwrapper ul li` is more specific then just `li.menuselected` so you can use

```
.menuwrapper ul li.menuselected {
    background-color:#6679e9;
    border-bottom:solid 1px white;
    width:190px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/45v1z7yk/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `.menuselected` is being applied to the li, not the ul.

Your CSS target should just be `.menuwrapper ul li.menuselected`

---

You could also change the JS to add the class to the parent ul.

```
$(this).parent().addClass("menuselected");
```

---

Also: you may consider clearing the `.menuselected` class before assigning it to the clicked li. That way, you'll only ever have one selected li.

```
$(".menuselected").removeClass("menuselected");
$(this).addClass("menuselected");
```

Unless of course you want to be able to select multiple, in which case, you may be looking for `toggleClass()`:

```
$(this).toggleClass("menuselected");
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS definition has been covered, you should add that `li`’s weight, like:

```
.menuwrapper li.menuselected{
    background-color:#6679e9;
    border-bottom:solid 1px white;
    width:190px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```